Azure pipeline does not pull the whole codebase from repo
Lately I notice that Azure DevOps center pipeline does not pull the whole source code from Azure repo.
pipeline:
stages:
  - stage: build_container
    displayName: "Build container"
    jobs:
      - job: create_container
        pool:
          name: Default
          demands:
            - Agent.Name -equals agent.linux
        steps:
          - checkout: self
            clean: true
            fetchTags: false
            lfs: false
            persistCredentials: true
            submodules: false
            continueOnError: false
            displayName: checkout repo
            name: checkout
            retryCountOnTaskFailure: 4

          - pwsh: |
              Set-Content -Path "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/agent/config/config.json" -Value 'some config'

Error is: ##[error]Cannot find path 'C:\AzureAgent\_work\3\s\agent\config\config.json' because it does not exist.
and it is actually true. When I login to my self-hosted agent machine I see that C:\AzureAgent_work\3\s\ folder contains only root files like README.md but no folders like \agent or other folders that do exist in repo
Why this happens ?
Checkout step complete successfully and does not throw any errors.
What I can do to fix that ?

Check whether the commit which the build runs for contains the folders and files you require. If not, trigger a new build for another commit which contains the required folders and files. Or ensure all the required folders and files are contained in the latest commit, then trigger a new build for the latest commit.

I found an answer
For some reason the git was configured for sparse checkout in the same folders where Azure tried to pull the files. So all the checkout and pull commands was running in git configuration for sparse checkout. This was causing this issue.
Once I reset this state everything start working as expected
